# jquery selects neighbour elements instead the one i want to select

Tags: jquery

This is an alphabetical table i created that shows the top products from each Letter.
[image: The table]

I wanted to Add some jquery so when a user click a Letter, after the page is refreshed , that letter will have a different css that indicates wich letter is "active" .

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function yo(alpha) {

$('#alpha_ul li a ').removeClass("activeyo");
alpha.addClass("activeyo");

}          
$("#alpha_ul li a").click(function () {
            if (localStorage) localStorage['alpha'] = $(this).closest('li').index();
            yo($(this));
        });      

     if (localStorage && localStorage.alpha) {
    yo( $("#alpha_ul li a").eq(localStorage.alpha) );
} 
});
```

When i click the first row of table (# - F) the script works allright.But if i click from the 2nd till the last row, it selects the N+row element ! ( as you can see in the picture i selected "K" but the "L" letter has the active css.At the 3rd row  if i click "N" the "P" will get the active css, etc. )

I tried many ways to edit a bit the script such as using $(this).parent('li') but that selects the "#" element.

each table element is a "li" with float left , seperated by a  every 7 "li" . So from what i understand its probably the Html code i used that makes the jquery to select wrong elements.So what would be the appropriate selector to use instead of closest() ?

This is the complete way how i generate the table if i didnt explain it well for someone:

```
<div <?php /* if ($checkstate == "" || $checkstate == NULL) {echo $swapstyle1; } */ ?>  id="full_table">
<div id="alpha_main_div">
<h3 style="color: #504D4C;font-size:16px;font-weight:700;" class="headers">Womens Perfume List By Letter</h3>
<ul id = "alpha_ul">
<li><a href="#">#</a></li>
<?php
$letters = range('A','Z');
$counter = 1;
$table ="" ;
foreach ($letters as $let) {
    if ($counter < 7 ) {
        $table .= '<li><a href="' . $link . '?letter=' . $let .'">'. $let . '</a></li>';
        $counter++;
        }
        else {
        $table .= '<br clear="left"/>';
        $table .= '<li><a  href="' . $link . '?letter=' . $let .'">' . $let . '</a></li>';
        $counter=1;
        }
        }
    $table.='<li>&nbsp;</li>';
    $table.= '</div></ul>';
    echo $table;
    echo '<br clear="left"/>';


?>
```

[the fiddle that shows what happening](http://jsfiddle.net/4cv99530/7/)

Comment: Can you prepare a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4cv99530/7/ this is exactly what is happening. Try to click the "L" and u will see that the "M" is selected !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "br" elements affect the index value you try to get. Remove the "br" elements and use fixed width on "ul" element to achive what you want to do. here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cv99530/10/)

here is how the ul element should look like:

```
<ul id="alpha_ul">
    <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
    <li><a href="A">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="B">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="C">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="D">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="E">E</a></li>
    <li><a href="F">F</a></li>    
    <li><a href="G">G</a></li>
    <li><a href="H">H</a></li>
    <li><a href="I">I</a></li>
    <li><a href="J">J</a></li>
    <li><a href="K">K</a></li>
    <li><a href="L">L</a></li>
    <li><a href="M">M</a></li>    
    <li><a href="N">N</a></li>
    <li><a href="O">O</a></li>
    <li><a href="P">P</a></li>
    <li><a href="Q">Q</a></li>
    <li><a href="R">R</a></li>
    <li><a href="S">S</a></li>
    <li><a href="T">T</a></li>    
    <li><a href="U">U</a></li>
    <li><a href="X">X</a></li>
    <li><a href="V">V</a></li>
    <li><a href="W">W</a></li>
    <li><a href="Y">Y</a></li>
    <li><a href="Z">Z</a></li>        
</ul>
```

and its style:

```
ul#alpha_ul {
list-style-type:none; 
width:300px;
}
```

Comment: That actually worked!But still cant understand why would it affect the index value!

Comment: because the <br /> elements are the children of the <ul> element in your code.

Comment: It's because you were getting the index of the `LI` elements (`$(this).closest('li').index()`) within the collection (via `$("#alpha_ul li a")`), but then using that index to refer to a specific child of the `UL`, which included (did not filter out) the `BR` elements. Note that if you clicked on `S` it would actually select `U` (2 letters away) because of the second `BR` tag before the `S`